# How to create below chart with E'chart JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have use the echart js and now create this type of chart with e'chart. it is posible with E'chart JS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im7mG.png)

Comment: refer this -
https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=bar-brush

Comment: http://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=xByWEvMqQf

Answer (score 0):

`var dataAll = [
            [20,14,28,29,200,9,24,20,14,28,29,200,9,24,20,14,28,29,200,9,24,20,14,28,29,200,9,24,20,14,28,29,200,9,24,20,14,28,29,200,9,24],
            [2,7,3,2,5,1,8,2,7,3,2,5,1,8,2,7,3,2,5,1,8,2,7,3,2,5,1,8,2,7,3,2,5,1,8,2,7,3,2,5,1,8],
            [34,15,30,53,65,15,48,34,15,30,53,65,15,48,34,15,30,53,65,15,48,34,15,30,53,65,15,48,34,15,30,53,65,15,48,34,15,30,53,65,15,48],
            [38,12,35,58,68,16,49,38,12,35,58,68,16,49,38,12,35,58,68,16,49,38,12,35,58,68,16,49,38,12,35,58,68,16,49,38,12,35,58,68,16,49],
        ];

option = {

```
        color: ['#fff'],

        tooltip : {
            trigger: 'axis',
            axisPointer : {            
                type : 'shadow'        
            }
        },
        legend: [{
            data: ['Biding', 'Cancel', 'Cancel By User'],
            align: 'left',
        },
        {
            data: ['Driver Rating'],
            align: 'left',
            bottom:'10%',
        },
        ],

        grid: [
            {x: '10%', y: '5%', width: '85%', height: '30%'},

            {x: '10%', y2: '18.3%', width: '85%', height: '30%'},

        ],
        //calculable : true,
        xAxis : [
            {type:'category',gridIndex: 0, data : ['Operator 1', 'Operator 2', 'Operator 3', 'Operator 4', 'Operator 5', 'Operator 6', 'Operator 7','Operator 8', 'Operator 9', 'Operator 10', 'Operator 11', 'Operator 12', 'Operator 13', 'Operator 14', 'Operator 15','Operator 16', 'Operator 17', 'Operator 18', 'Operator 19', 'Operator 20', 'Operator 21','Operator 1', 'Operator 2', 'Operator 3', 'Operator 4', 'Operator 5', 'Operator 6', 'Operator 7','Operator 8', 'Operator 9', 'Operator 10', 'Operator 11', 'Operator 12', 'Operator 13', 'Operator 14', 'Operator 15','Operator 16', 'Operator 17', 'Operator 18', 'Operator 19', 'Operator 20', 'Operator 21'],  axisTick: {show: false},nameGap:'40',axisLabel: {fontWeight: 'bold',rotate: 60}},
            {type:'category',gridIndex: 1, data : ['Operator 1', 'Operator 2', 'Operator 3', 'Operator 4', 'Operator 5', 'Operator 6', 'Operator 7','Operator 8', 'Operator 9', 'Operator 10', 'Operator 11', 'Operator 12', 'Operator 13', 'Operator 14', 'Operator 15','Operator 16', 'Operator 17', 'Operator 18', 'Operator 19', 'Operator 20', 'Operator 21','Operator 1', 'Operator 2', 'Operator 3', 'Operator 4', 'Operator 5', 'Operator 6', 'Operator 7','Operator 8', 'Operator 9', 'Operator 10', 'Operator 11', 'Operator 12', 'Operator 13', 'Operator 14', 'Operator 15','Operator 16', 'Operator 17', 'Operator 18', 'Operator 19', 'Operator 20', 'Operator 21'],axisLabel:{show:false},axisTick: {show: false}},
        ],
        yAxis : [
            {type:'value',gridIndex: 0,splitLine:{lineStyle:{type:'dashed'}},  axisTick: {show: false},axisLabel: {show: false},axisLine: {show: false},splitLine: {show: false}},
            {type:'value',gridIndex: 1,inverse:true,splitLine:{lineStyle:{type:'dashed'}}, axisTick: {show: false},axisLabel: {show: false},axisLine: {show: false},splitLine: {show: false}},

        ],
        /*dataZoom: [
        {
            show: true,
            realtime: true,
            start: 1,
            end: 50,
            xAxisIndex: [0, 1]
        },
        {
            type: 'inside',
            realtime: true,
            start: 1,
            end: 50,
            xAxisIndex: [0, 1]
        }
    ],*/
        series : [
            {
                name: 'Biding',
                type: 'bar',
                xAxisIndex: 0,
                yAxisIndex: 0,
                data: dataAll[0],
                stack: 'Total amount',
                itemStyle:{color:'#62cf72'},
                barWidth:20,
                label: {
                    normal: {
                        show: false,
                        position: 'top'
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                name: 'Cancel',
                type: 'bar',
                xAxisIndex: 0,
                yAxisIndex: 0,
                stack: 'Total amount',
                data: dataAll[2],
                itemStyle: {color: '#fa76ee'},
                barWidth:20,

                label: {
                    normal: {
                        show: false,
                        position: 'top'
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                name: 'Cancel By User',
                type: 'bar',
                xAxisIndex: 0,
                yAxisIndex: 0,
                stack: 'Total amount',
                data: dataAll[3],
                itemStyle: {color: '#739ffe'},
                barWidth:20,

                label: {
                    normal: {
                        show: false,
                        position: 'top'
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                name: 'Driver Rating',
                type: 'bar',
                xAxisIndex: 1,
                yAxisIndex: 1,
                data: dataAll[1],
                itemStyle: {color: '#feb082'},
                barWidth:20,
                label: {
                    normal: {
                        show: false,
                        position: 'bottom'
                    }
                },
            },

        ]
    });
```

`